# JBoss Application Server 7.0.1 CRUD Application

Tags: java, mysql, jboss

I am new to JBoss AS and wondering where to get the basic nuts and bolts to build a simple CRUD application. If someone could provide me the answer it would be helpful. I have to use JBoss AS 7.0.1. Have seen the basic app example's but couldnt find much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a great tutorial for JBoss Application Server using JBoss Tools (the Eclipse-based IDE, but you could JBoss Developer Studio also). The tutorial gives you a CRUD example to build and deploy.

- Tutorial: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/2.0.0.GA/seam/en/html/crud_database_application.html
- JBoss Tools IDE: http://www.jboss.org/tools.html